# Google analytics anonymous ip

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm working on some wordpress sites, using the Divi theme. I have added this code in the head (Divi -> integration):

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', '<GA_TRACKING_ID>', { 'anonymize_ip': true });
```

I have replaced '<GA_TRACKING_ID>' with the right id.

When I inspect it to see if it works, I can't find aip=1. It only says "ep.anonymize_ip: true" at the end of the Request Url and the Query String Parameter inside the collect...>.

Does this make the IP anonymous?

Answer (score 0):

if you use **Google Analytics 4**, or the one with the code in this pattern `G-XXXXXXX` (instead of `UA-XXXXXXX-XX`), you don't have to specify the `anonymize_ip` since it is already active by default.